How to write a full dynamic ruleset for php?
I have a rule set that I saved in the database. This rule set is completely dynamic. It is responsible for controlling the selected option and the adapted structure. I have prepared a code example in a simple and static way. However, I could not find how I can dynamically use the "and" and "or" operator dynamically, especially the top level conditionals in parentheses.
The most logical way out for this structure is to use eval(), but I want to enable this feature on the server. Using this feature requires a lot of responsibility.
<?php 
/*
How can I dynamically set up the if or and structure for the following Scenario?
*/


/*
Please don't worry about the code being static. The whole structure will work dynamically.

This way I get a condition data from the database.
*/
$conditionRule = array(
    'name' => 'TestControl',
    'process'=>'block',
    'conditionRules' => array(
        0 => array(
            'parameter'=>'cartFirstNo',
            'operator' => 'in_array',
            'value'=>'520019',
            'resumeOperator'=>'and',
        ),
        1 => array(
            'parameter'=>'paymentAmount',
            'operator' => '>',
            'value'=>100,
            'resumeOperator'=>'and',
        ),
        2 => array(
            'parameter'=>'ipDifferendCardCount',
            'operator' => '>',
            'value'=>'3',
            'resumeOperator'=>'and',
        ),
        3 => array(
            'parameter'=>'ipDailyPaymentCount',
            'operator' => '>',
            'value'=>'3',
            'resumeOperator'=>'or',
        ),
        4 => array(
            'parameter'=>'buyerEmail',
            'operator' => 'in_array',
            'value'=>'blackListMail'
        ),
    )
);

/*BlackList Records of the System. This query can also be connected to an api end. Please do not be interested in static. */
$blackList = array(
    'blackListMail'=>[
        'test@gmail.com',
        'test1@gmail.com',
        'test13@gmail.com',
        'test134@gmail.com',
        'test1345@gmail.com',
    ]
);


/*Here we pass all the data needed for our rule check to the variable. */
$checkForDatas = array();
foreach ($conditionRule['conditionRules'] as $key)
{
    if($key['parameter'] == 'cartFirstNo')
    {
        /*First 6 digits of the Card Number of that transaction*/
        $checkForDatas['cartFirstNo'] = '546321';
    }
    
    if($key['parameter'] == 'paymentAmount')
    {
        /*Payment Amount for that Transaction*/
        $checkForDatas['paymentAmount'] = 80;
    }
    
    if($key['parameter'] == 'ipDifferendCardCount')
    {
        /*How many different cards the ip address of that transaction uses*/
        $checkForDatas['ipDifferendCardCount'] = 6;
    }
    
    if($key['parameter'] == 'ipDailyPaymentCount')
    {
        /*How many different payments the IP address of that transaction has made in the last 24 hours*/
        $checkForDatas['ipDailyPaymentCount'] = 6;
    }
    if($key['parameter'] == 'buyerEmail')
    {
        /*How many different payments the IP address of that transaction has made in the last 24 hours*/
        $checkForDatas['buyerEmailAdress'] = 'test9999@gmail.com';
    }
}
/*
The above compiled checking mechanism needs to dynamically check the following statement. 
How can I dynamicize "and", "or" bla bla "and" bla bla "and" bla bla "and" (bla bla "or" blabla "or") in the following if clause?
*/

if ($checkForDatas['cartFirstNo'] == '520019' && $checkForDatas['paymentAmount'] > 100 && $checkForDatas['ipDailyPaymentCount'] > 3 && $checkForDatas['ipDifferendCardCount'] > 3  || (in_array($checkForDatas['buyerEmailAdress'],$blackList['blackListMail'])))
{
    if ($conditionRule['process'] == 'block')
    {
        /*
        Operation Blocking is executed
        */
    }
    elseif ($conditionRule['process'] == 'takeOfReview')
    {
        /*
        The administrator will review the process
        */
    }
}


I can't tell if it is 0 AND 1 AND 2 AND 3 OR 4, (0 AND 1 AND 2 AND 3) OR 4, (0 AND 1 AND 2) AND 3 OR 4 or (0 AND 1 AND 2) AND (3 OR 4)

"I have a rule set that I saved in the database" - just to warn you, starting out with the string-based ruleset might make this much harder to build and even harder to extend in the future. It might be better to build the logic first with static values, and then derive the serialization format from that.

@ChrisHaas Thank you for your suggestion. I just checked the "Symfony/ExpressionLanguage" library, it works quite well for me. I just need to save the rule structure as text.
Or I need to produce a text result from the array structure.
